# Extending this function to $\mathbf R$

Tags: functions, continuity

I have the following function that is defined for $x$: zero or positive (natural number) power of 10.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\log_{10}x}\left({1\over 2}\right)^{k+1}$$
$$1\to 1/2$$
$$10\to 3/4$$
$$100\to 7/8$$
$$\vdots$$
How can this function of $x$ be extended to $x\in \mathbf R, x > 0$ so that it is differentiable in this domain? I want it to converge to $0$ when $x\to 0$ and converge to $1$ when $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Draw the graph: in this case it is simply isolated points. Connect the dots by straight line, for example. This is the graph of one possible extension of your function. Note that this just *one of the* many possible extensions. (even when we insist on continuity there are infinitely many.)

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. It is

$$1-\left({1\over 2}\right)^{(\log_{10}x)+1}$$

Comment: I edited your answer because it wasn't clear what you were taking the $\log()$ of. Please make sure I was correct.